# SwiftUI WCSession isReachable only when looking at watch

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm building a watch and iphone ios companion app and having issues reliably triggering messages between the two applications. In both applications I trigger the WC onInit in a viewmodel that loads, these seem to register correctly:

```
        if !WCSession.default.isReachable {
            if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
                WCSession.default.delegate = self
                WCSession.default.activate()
            }
        }
```

Then on a view on each of the devices I have the following code, with CONTEXT replaced by either WATCH or IPHONE

```
.onReceive(timer) { time in
            if WCSession.default.isReachable {
                print("Checking WCSession CONTEXT SUCCESS")
            }
            else{
                print("Checking WCSession CONTEXT FAILURE")
            }
        }
```

What I'm finding is I get SUCCESS messages only when I'm looking at the watch, it goes into some sleep or inactive mode unless the IWATCH is rotated and I am looking at it (or I tap it for example). My goal is to start an IWatch activity session from the Phone however the messages fail because I'm not looking at my watch. Is there a way to reliably send/receive messages regardless of if I'm looking at the watch?